# Detecting mounted USB devices in OS X

Tags: macos, usb

So I trying to detect mounted and unmounted usb devices in OS X on my Mac Mini

I have followed other guides, but it seems I do not receive any notifications.

This is the code that I have, which I have also tried to place in the view controller class to no avail.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)deviceMounted: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Mounted");
}
- (void)deviceUnmounted: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Unmounted");
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
   NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter2 = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];

    // Notification for Mountingthe USB device
    [notificationCenter2 addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceMounted:)  name:NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification object:nil];

    // Notification for Un-Mountingthe USB device
    [notificationCenter2 addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceUnmounted:)  name:NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way in which your code is trying to log is incorrect, `NSLog` is what you need here:

```
- (void)deviceMounted: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Mounted");
}
- (void)deviceUnmounted: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Unmounted");
}
```

**Result**:

```
2015-02-27 04:07:00.593 notify[32431:16256290] Mounted
2015-02-27 04:07:11.587 notify[32431:16256290] Unmounted
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I had my own log macro there, I have updated the example (and my code) with your suggestion, but I still don't get the notifications (the logging is working otherwise).

Comment: How are you wanting to be notified though... Notifications can be dialogs, alerts, etc. Currently the code you've got just observes the unmounting, mounting process - but there's nothing telling it what to do from there.

Comment: As long as I actually get the notificiation, I should be okey to go from there to perform any other tasks, for now I jsut want to get the log text. Okey, I just realized that the problem is that I expected to get a notification for any plugged in usb device, but apparently this code applies only for devices like memory sticks, in which case it does work properly. In my case I would like to identify a connected FTDI device...

Comment: Yep, you'll need slightly different code to handle that. Your code does indeed work for `memory sticks`, `.dmg's`, `etc.`, as one would expect.

Comment: This might help: https://code.google.com/p/ump-cocoa/source/browse/trunk/UMPFramework/FTDI/FTDIDeviceBrowser.m?r=2

Comment: It uses `AMSerial` (https://github.com/pizthewiz/AMSerialPort), which is the key to making the entire thing work. If you need more examples look there :)